# py-abac pdp implementation failing for correct "rules" match also

Tags: python, abac

I am trying to implement py-abac for ABAC, Even if correct policies are getting retrieved from the storage, while the policy evaluation part is always giving "Deny" case. I tried to check the issue and found that even for matching rules also somehow it is giving none and always return deny. There is no resources or documentation available other than official documentation. If anybody tried py-abac please provide some lead. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the format. In py-abac, PDP only gives correct output if the format is correct (following a specific format). If the format is different it causes a problem as mentioned in the question.